# Can I spy with sinon a function call in an external module function?

Tags: node.js, sinon

I have a module:

```
let xmlParser = require('./myTools').xmlParser;

function extractDataAndWrite(xmldata) {
    let doc = xmlParser(xmldata);
    ...
}

module.exports = {
    extractDataAndWrite,
};
```

now I want test the call of `xmlParser` in `extractDataAndWrite`:

```
var extractDataAndWrite = require('../services/importData.js').extractDataAndWrite;
var mytools = require('./myTools');

var sinon = require('sinon');

describe('Test extractDataAndWrite', function() {
    it('call xmlParser', function(done) {
        var xmlParserSpy = sinon.spy(mytools, 'xmlParser');

        extractDataAndWrite("someXML");

        console.log('xmlParserSpy: ' + xmlParserSpy.callCount);
        done();
    });
});
```

I expect get `xmlParserSpy.callCount == 1` but it is 0!
My spy is not working, what must I change?

Comment: added an answer that explains why it's not working, as well as a technique that can fix your issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that when you create a `spy` on a function, you are replacing that function reference with a new function. That means that people that reference the old function will not use the new function. In your case, things are not working, as you wrap the *exported* function reference in `mytools`' after your own module has already referenced the old function reference.

The general techniques you need to look into are called dependency injection and link seams. The Sinon docs has a [good tutorial on the latter](http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/), using `proxyquire`.

Essentially you would have this:

```
const proxyquire = require('proxyquire');
const toolsStub = createToolsStub();
const importData = proxyquire('../services/importData.js', {
    './myTools': toolsStub
});

function createToolsStub(){
    return { xmlParser : sinon.stub().returns({mydoc:{foo:'bar'}};
}
```

Then later on in your test you could check the `xmlParser` for calls

```
assert(toolsStub.xmlParser.calledWith('arg1', 'arg2');
```

Comment: https://github.com/sinonjs/demo-proxyquire is very useful. But it working not with own modules.

Comment: My changes are:
lib/mytools.js:
function xmlParser(xmldata) {
    return false;
}

module.exports = {
    xmlParser
};
does-file-exist.js:
var mtools = require("../lib/mytools");

function doesFileExist(path) {
    return mtools.xmlParser(path);
    // return fs.existsSync(path);
}
does-file-exist.test.js
doesFileExist = proxyquire("../lib/does-file-exist", {
            mtools: {
                xmlParse: existsSyncStub
            }
        });
Test fail!!! Why?

Comment: When you are seeking help, it helps to say what fails :-) And `proxyquire` works _fine_ with local modules... But anyway, I extracted your code, formatted it and [put it on jsbin](https://jsbin.com/fokafafive/edit?js). It is easy to see why this does not work: you  do not specify the right path to the module. I will update my jsbin with code that is correct.

Comment: P.S. If it solves your problem, consider marking the answer as solved.

Comment: I take your fix but test on local module fail:
https://jsfiddle.net/Gerd/7gkzrjhp/
On log output (jsfiddle) you see stub not working! 
existsSyncStub.returns(true); ==> should set return on testtime to "true" but it is "false"

Comment: The devil's in the nuts and bolts :-)

Comment: We take pull requests 